# Can I get String from memory of another program?

Tags: c#, string, memory, text, ram

Thanks for help in advance.

I already know how to find memory addresses for numerical values and read\write them in ram. (using C#).
What I want to do is the same for any text in any program. But I don't know if it's even possible.

So for instance, can I access opened notepad.exe memory to extract String which written inside of it?
Right now I am doing this and it returns garbage:

```
Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
String stringaddress = "00401110";
int address = int.Parse(stringaddress, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
int bytesRead;
byte[] value = MemoryAccess.ReadMemory(process, address, 2000000, out bytesRead);
byte[] buf = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), 
                                Encoding.UTF8, value);
int count = buf.Length;
String tempString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf, 0, count);
```

What I finally want is to be able to find specific window in program and copy all the text inside of it.

Comment: The memory address of the textbox string will be different every time you start up notepad (or some other application). Unless you can get the ***right*** memory address every time your application runs, this doesn't seem possible.

Comment: If you want to grab a text from a specific window (form) you can use WinAPI: EnumWindows to find out the window and GetWindowText to obtain the desired text.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, I think he wants to get the text from the textbox control in Notepad. GetWindowText cannot retrieve the text of a control in another application.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the address doesn't change at all.

using [ProcessMemoryReader](https://code.google.com/p/cbloader/source/browse/trunk/ProcessMemoryReader.cs?r=5), you can try something like this.

```
ProcessMemoryReader memoryReader = new ProcessMemoryReader();
memoryReader.ReadProcess = process;
memoryReader.OpenProcess();
```

...

```
public string GetString(int memoryAddress, uint bytes) {
    int bytesRead;
    byte[] memoryValue = memoryReader.ReadProcessMemory((IntPtr)memoryAddress, bytes, out bytesRead);
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.Default;
    string result = encoding.GetString(memoryValue, 0, (int)bytes);
    result = result.TrimEnd('\0');
    return result;
}
```